# Applying the collections.counter() on UTF-8

Tags: collections, utf-8, python-2.7, frequency

I have a list consisting of non-English text in utf-8 format.
Therefore, when I attempt to print a single word, it gives me this:
u'\u0648\u0627\u0644\u0623\u0631\u0646\u0628'

Therefore, in order to print it as the original word, I have to loop it and it will output correctly, as the original word.

I want to find the 5 most frequent words.
When storing the words into the collections.counter() function, they enter as the unicode format.
How do I access the word inside the counter() in order to print the top 5 most frequent words.

I have done the following code: (txt being my text file)

> > > words = [w for w in txt.split()]

will print out

> > > [u'\ufeff\u0643\u0627\u0646', u'\u064a\u0627', u'\u0645\u0627', 
> > >               ...u'\u0643\u0627\u0646', u'\u0641\u064a', u'\u0642\u062f\u064a\u0645']

I therefore loop it to get the desired output (I don't know why)

```
 >>> for w in words:
        print w,
```

will print out

> > > كان يا ما كان

I use the counter() function to find the most frequent words

```
 >>> count = collections.Counter(words)
 >>> print count.most_common(5)
```

will print out

```
 >>> [(u'\u0627\u0644\u0633\u0644\u062d\u0641\u0627\u0629', 5),
  (u'\u0627\u0644\u0645\u063a\u0631\u0648\u0631', 3), 
(u'\u0627\u0644\u0623\u0631\u0646\u0628', 2), (u'\u060c', 2), 
(u'\u0648\u0627\u0644\u0623\u0631\u0646\u0628', 2)]
```

I want to access each word and loop it to print it out WITH it's frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your first example, you can just print the word directly to get the original (I can't read Arabic, so this may be wrong):

```
>>> print u'\u0648\u0627\u0644\u0623\u0631\u0646\u0628'
والأرنب
```

If you are doing this through the interpreter and you do not explicitly use `print`, you will still see the unicode representation:

```
>>> u'\u0648\u0627\u0644\u0623\u0631\u0646\u0628'
u'\u0648\u0627\u0644\u0623\u0631\u0646\u0628'
```

Therefore, you can just call `print` to see the actual word:

```
>>> l
[(u'\u0627\u0644\u0633\u0644\u062d\u0641\u0627\u0629', 5),
 (u'\u0627\u0644\u0645\u063a\u0631\u0648\u0631', 3), 
 (u'\u0627\u0644\u0623\u0631\u0646\u0628', 2), (u'\u060c', 2), 
 (u'\u0648\u0627\u0644\u0623\u0631\u0646\u0628', 2)]
>>> for el in l:
    print el[0], el[1]


السلحفاة 5
المغرور 3
الأرنب 2
، 2
والأرنب 2
```